# I can't pause play video on tablecell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I used to load the video on `UITableViewCell` by using avplayer. I can load the video on `UITableViewCell` but I can't pause/play the video. I cant do any basic functionality like increase/decrease the volume. please any one help me to solve this issues.
here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        let cell: FeedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VedioCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell

        let videoURL = NSURL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
          player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

        playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 200)
       cell.PlayerView?.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
          player.play()

    return cell
    }
```

I used the avplayer here but I can't access

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: should the user decide when to stop / play etc the video or is it based on some sort of automation ?

Comment: user decide the stop and play like avplayercontroller ..like when we play the video in avplayercontroller we can drag and drop paise and play increse the volome etc...like i ahve to do with the video

Comment: You should provide a little more detail about this, just like @Mingebag said. How do you want to pause / stop video, with tap on cell? Will there be more than one video in TableView?

Comment: What does UITableView's cellForRowAt method have to do with firing an action?

Comment: i  need to do all default action ..if we using avplayer we can do with action in video but here i cant do with any action like pause play etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        {

```
        let cell: FeedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VedioCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell

        let player = playerArray[indexPath.row]
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 200)
       cell.PlayerView?.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        cell.play.tag = indexPath.row

        cell.play.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GetUpdatesButtonTouched), for: .touchUpInside)


               return cell
    }


 @IBAction func GetUpdatesButtonTouched(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        if sender.currentTitle == "Play" {
            for i in 0..<10{
                currentPlayer=playerArray[i]
                currentPlayer.pause()
                print("tag: \(sender.tag)")
                print("tag: \(playerArray)")
                currentPlayer=playerArray[sender.tag]
                print("tag: \(currentPlayer)")
                //  handleVideoChageSlider(("" as AnyObject) as! UISlider)
                currentPlayer.play()

                sender.setTitle("Pause", for: UIControlState.normal)

              //  let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
               let cell: FeedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at:sender.indexPath)as! FeedCell

                //print(currentCell.videoLabel.text)

                //cell.slider.tag=indexPath.row
                cell.slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleVideoChageSlider), for:.valueChanged )

            }
        }
        else if sender.currentTitle == "Pause"{
            for i in 0..<10{
                currentPlayer=playerArray[i]
                currentPlayer.pause()
                sender.setTitle("Play", for: UIControlState.normal)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

**1)** Declare a variable of `AVPlayer` in your `cell` class.

**2)** Inside `cellWillAppear` , instantiate this variable like

```
cell.avplayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
```

**3)** Inside `cellWillDisapper` , make `avplayer nil`

```
cell.avplayer = nil
```

**4)** To increase / decrease volume, use `avplayer` of that particular `cell` only.

Comment: thanks for answer the qestion ..but my doubt is i am using avplayer here ...for pause and play increase the volume is default action in avplayer but its not working for me

Answer (score -1):

maybe you should reuse the AVPlayerLayer , or the "https" cause it